# Hidden files in ubuntu files directory show up in GUI

Tags: ubuntu

I know that to show hidden files i use Ctrl+H. However, hidden files showing up has now become default on launch. How do I reverse this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

1.Click on the files launcher.
2.Right click on the directory that has this issue.
3.At this point a screen with the name *user properties* should pop up.
4.Click on the file image and it will give you a different display of your files directory.
5.In there you may right click and select the selections with which you wish to display your files.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> again.